# Button disappear in layout

Tags: android-layout, android-xml

Back button disappear even though i called layout below the recycler view, I can show the button if i set the height manually but i need to use "wrap_content" because not all devices have the same size. Im trying to add a back button on the bottom after the recycler view. pls help on why it dosent show..  Im new in android studio ive tried changing the layouts but dosent work..

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/colorLight">

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/search_view_bg"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:queryHint="Search"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"/>



    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/viewMain"
        android:layout_below="@id/searchView"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="187dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Go Back"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@id/viewMain"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/varela_round"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/round_back_white"
        />
    
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/searchView">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/viewMain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/back"
            android:layout_width="187dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/viewMain"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_back_white"
            android:fontFamily="@font/varela_round"
            android:text="Go Back"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**@xenxen101219 After SearchView Use NestedScrollView**